# Is there example of twin macro with nx workspace?

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, monorepo, nx-workspace

I'm trying to set up `nextjs`, `tailwind`, `styled-components`, and `twin.macro` inside `nx monorepo`.

The `styled-components` using `twin.macro` will be available inside `libs` of `nx repo` and can be used by `nextjs` apps available in `apps` directory.

The initial setup is done but when I tried using twin.macro inside the lib components it gave error:

```
error - ../../node_modules/import-fresh/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module'

Import trace for requested module:
../../node_modules/import-fresh/index.js
../../node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js
../../node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/index.js
../../node_modules/twin.macro/node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js
../../node_modules/twin.macro/macro.js
../../libs/global-styles/src/lib/Buttons/index.styles.tsx
../../libs/global-styles/src/lib/Buttons/index.tsx
../../libs/global-styles/src/index.ts
./pages/index.tsx

 1 | import tw from "twin.macro";
  2 | 
> 3 | export const StyledButton = tw.button`
    |                                      ^
  4 |     py-1.5
  5 |     px-4
  6 |     md:px-5
```